# attribute error in Django while making a urls.py file under my app

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

while i'm trying to create my first project and my first app i'm getting this error:

of course when i removed the url of my app view.py it works perfectly (the home screen)

```
.... 

  File "C:\Users\pegasus\barakcapitalcom\buildtradeapp\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    path('buildtradeapp/', views.index, name='index')
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'buildtradeapp.views' has no attribute 'index'
```

this is my app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('buildtradeapp/', views.index, name='index')
]
```

this is my app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")
```

this is my main project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from buildtradeapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('buildtradeapp/', include('buildtradeapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

what did i do wrong?

i'm trying to create my first app and first project,
printing hello world using django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your app level url pattern wrong. In your app urls.py, change `path('buildtradeapp/', views.index, name='index')` to `path('', views.index, name='index')` Also, you need to include your app_name like this `app_name = 'buildtradeapp'`

So your app urls.py should now look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'buildtradeapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```